# Varied colspan width bug

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, width, html-table

I'm trying to render a treeview in ASP.NET as follows (JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fNRKE/1/))

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col width="20" span="2" />
        <col width="*" /> // removing this width doesn't change anything
        <col width="20" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Top-level element</td>
        <td>(checkbox)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>(spacer)</td>
        <td colspan="2">Mid-level element</td>
        <td>(checkbox)</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>(spacer)</td>
    <td>(spacer)</td>
    <td colspan="1">Bottom</td>
    <td>(checkbox)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

where `(spacer)` is a 20px-wide cell that has treelines in it and `(checkbox)` is a checkbox, of which I'd like all to be aligned in the right-hand column.

In IE8 this renders as I expect - the `*`-width `col`, spanned with the spacer cells, expands enough to accomodate the longest item in the spanned cells.

```
| Top-level element     | [] |
| . | Mid-level element | [] |
| . | . |Bottom         | [] |
```

In IE7, it doesn't render correctly. The *-width `col` only expands enough to accomodate the cells actually in the penultimate column, not those that span across into it, and the other cells break onto multiple lines.

```
| Top-level      | [] |
| element        |    |
| . | Mid-level  | [] |
|   | element    |    |
| . | . | Bottom | [] |
```

Is there a way I can make IE7 lay this table out properly, while still keeping the table width dynamic? (I.e. without just giving the penultimate column or the table itself a fixed width.)

Alternatively, is there a way I can obtain this dynamic sizing using divs instead of a table?

A couple of other points:

- Setting individual cell widths doesn't work - IE7 seems to ignore them, and that leads to the tree-lines all being out of line.
- Setting `table-layout: fixed` fixes the alignment, but in IE7 (again, not in IE8) it makes the table 100% wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but even in a `colgroup` I'm pretty sure a width of `*` is invalid. I've only heard of using the star-sizes with a preceeding number.

Have you tried a more "standard" way of doing this by defining a header row with fixed widths, and leaving the width off the central column? So long as the table's width is `100%` or at the very least dynamic past the point of the fixed width columns, it should span the remainder.

After discussion and playing around, JS seems to be the best solution:

```
<table id="test" cellpadding="0">
    <tr><td style="width: 20px"></td><td style="width: 20px"></td><td></td><td style="width: 20px"></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Top-level element</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td>+</td>
        <td colspan="2">Mid-level element</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td>+</td>
        <td>Bottom</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Setting to: " + document.getElementById('test').clientWidth);
    document.getElementById('test').style.width = document.getElementById('test').clientWidth + 'px';
    document.getElementById('test').style.tableLayout = 'fixed';
</script>
```

Comment: I've just checked and having/not having `width="*"` doesn't make a difference - IE8 expands the column, IE7 doesn't. I'm hoping to keep the "text" column as narrow as possible without forcing line breaks, so a 100% table width or fixed column width defeats this.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't talking about the `colgroup`, I meant removing that and having a header row with `td`s and explicitly defined widths.

Comment: (sorry rudi, pressed enter halfway through my comment and have edited it.)

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, well, doing what I suggested seems to work in IE10 standards all the way through to IE5 quirks (Using dev tools to switch renderer @ IE10). See updated answer with sample code

Comment: Wait, what? Your code seems to work... I need to look into this :)

Comment: Yeah the only thing is that 'Bottom' appears to be pushed out to the right a bit, but I'm sure that can be tweaked away :/ In 'Quirks' mode @ IE10 it removes the space but no idea why!

Comment: Ah yes... This was the _other_ rubbish IE7 behaviour I saw - completely ignoring the widths set on the TDs themselves :(

Comment: Ah, I made a booboo and surrounded the first `td`s in a `th` instead of a `tr`, if you change that, it works exactly as expected across the board. (Answer updated)

Comment: I'm afraid not - `th` or `tr`, IE7 doesn't respect the width of the second column. In fact if you use `tr`, it also doesn't respect the width of the first column either.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17218/discussion-between-rudi-visser-and-rawling)

Comment: The JS fix is brilliant, nice one :)